# WinSock Chunked Data Encoding

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2, http-chunked

When I connect to some sites, it gives me:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Connection: close

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Date: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 18:49:53 GMT   


fff8
```

And at the end of the file, it looks like:

```
</script><!-- vBadvanced 1-3-9-4-8-0 -->

</body>
</html

1

>

0
```

But when I do stackoverflow.com, it prints out perfectly fine.. It may have extra blank lines in the source but that's fine.. Why does the other site add numbers though?

How can I fix it? Also, how can I separate that header from the html itself?

My code is as follows:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501

#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void Get(string WebPage)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    string Address;
    struct addrinfo *result;
    struct sockaddr_in  *sockaddr_ipv4;

    char Buffer[99000];

    string Header = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    Header += "Host: " + WebPage + "\r\n";
    Header += "Connection: close\r\n";
    Header += "\r\n";

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) return;

    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    getaddrinfo(WebPage.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &result);
    if (result->ai_family == AF_INET)
    {
        sockaddr_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) result->ai_addr;
        Address = inet_ntoa(sockaddr_ipv4->sin_addr);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);


    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    memset(&SockAddr, 0, sizeof(SockAddr));
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(Address.c_str());

    if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) return;

    if (send(Socket, Header.c_str(), Header.size(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) return;
    shutdown(Socket, SD_SEND);

    std::string Response;

    int bytes = 1;
    while (bytes > 0)
    {
        bytes = recv(Socket, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 0);
        Buffer[bytes] = '\0';
        Response.append(Buffer, bytes);
    };

    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
}

int main()
{
    Get("google.com");
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't check for error from the `recv` call.

Comment: If you're doing HTTP on Windows from C or C++, you ought to look at WinInet (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331.aspx) or WinHTTP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Each of these hex numbers (chunk length) is followed by the actual chunk data (payload) of the specified size, immediately followed by another chunk length. If chunk length is zero, no further data bytes follow (eof). These elements are separated by line breaks.
I'm not sure, whether the content you posted can be catenated correctly, it seems, you'd need to handle multiple, contiguous line breaks. Just look at the page and its source in a browser.

EDIT:

Just found this sniffing tool, it displays all the details I'd like to know in your situation:

http://web-sniffer.net/

Comment: I tried splitting the Response string by CRLF, still cannot figure out how to find which chunk is which or how to remove the header data from the top of the file.. It's ok though. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Each header attribute is terminated with CRLF, the header itself is terminated by an additional CRLF (can be regarded as an empty header attribute). After that, you should be at the position of the first chunk length (fff8). It seems, that you've got one additional line break when copying the data (maybe a conversion issue, where CR and LF got separate line breaks).

Comment: Note, that chunked encoding allows the server to leave out the 'Content-Length' attribute. You should implement a check, for the zero chunk length at the end or the size specified in the header for another Transfer-Encoding.

Comment: @Sam: [RFC 2616 Section 3.6.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) defines the format of chunks. Each chunk has two CRLFs in it - one after the chunk size, and one after the chunk data. When `Transfer-Encoding` is present, `Content-Length` is not supposed to be present, and if it is present then it must be ignored. This is clearly stated in [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4).

Comment: With these two `CRLF`'s, I meant the contiguous ones in the content of the question, (or do I just fail to get, what you mean?). The ability (or more correctly, the requirement) to drop `Content-Length` makes up the advantage of chunked mode as you stated. IMHO, these web 'standards' are like a jungle. In case of a transfer encoding, which does not have a termination rule, the length would again be required beforehand when assuming, that one would use something like quoted printable encoding as in a superior MIME container, which in turn requires an unique separator anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This function will 'unchunk' your HTTP data - In VB6, but you'll get the idea (really OLD CODE)

```
Private Function UnChunk(Indata As String) As String
  If InStr(LCase(Indata), "transfer-encoding:") = 0 And InStr(LCase(Indata), "chunked") = 0 Then
    'not chunked, so return the input
    UnChunk = Indata
    Exit Function
  End If
  'can't let this crash
  On Error GoTo returnInData

  Dim crlfstart As Long
  Dim crlfend As Long
  Dim chunksize As Long

  'first, get header, which ends with 2 line feeds
  crlfstart = InStr(Indata, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
  If crlfstart = 0 Then
    'invalid http
    UnChunk = Indata
    Exit Function
  End If
  UnChunk = Left(Indata, crlfstart + 2)

  'start looking for vbCrLf
  crlfstart = InStr(crlfstart + 2, Indata, vbCrLf)
  Do While crlfstart > 0
    'find the next vbCrLf
    crlfend = InStr(crlfstart + 1, Indata, vbCrLf)

    If crlfend > crlfstart And crlfend - crlfstart < 10 Then
      'convert the HEX string to the chunksize
      chunksize = Val("&h" & Mid(Indata, crlfstart + 2, crlfend - (crlfstart + 2)))
      'by spec, if 0 then no more data
      If chunksize > 0 Then
        'there's more data
        'this should be unnecessary, but one more test
        If Mid(Indata, crlfend + 2 + chunksize, 2) = vbCrLf Then
          UnChunk = UnChunk & Mid(Indata, crlfend + 2, chunksize)
        Else
          'oops, failed
          Exit Do
        End If
      Else
        'there's no more data so return what we have
        Exit Function
      End If
    End If
    'look again
    crlfstart = InStr(crlfstart + 1, Indata, vbCrLf)
  Loop
  'just in case this fails, return the input data
returnInData:
  UnChunk = Indata
End Function
```